# Why Flutter needs Kotlin?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

In Flutter 2.10 or above, you will need to ensure that your app supports an up-to-date Kotlin version. This will typically be version 1.5.31 or higher.

You can do this by updating the Kotlin version in your app's android/build.gradle file:

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
...
}

Why Kotlin is needed for Java-based projects? Flutter uses Dart to compile.

Is this due to Gradle dependency or any other SDK or framework requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's Embedder is the native OS application that hosts all Flutter content. On Android, Flutter is (by default) loaded into an Activity. You can read more about it in [Flutter architectural overview](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#platform-embedding).
If you open the `android` folder in your Flutter project, you'll find a Kotlin Android app there.

Comment: I'll will also find a Java app there?

Comment: No, unless you specify `--android-language Java` when creating your Flutter project. Kotlin is sued by default.

Comment: I've chosen Java already (not default). That's why I still wonder why Flutter requires Kotlin then. That's the question. Who uses Kotlin, where?

Comment: You should update you question to reflect this, arguably vital, information.

Comment: Do you mean, if I select Java as android-language, then Flutter will never use (depend) Kotlin (even internally i mean)? So I can safely delete "buildscript { ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' ... }" in build.gradle, right?

Comment: No, I mean that your question should be updated to reflect that you're *not* asking about the embedder, but rather why Kotlin is needed for Java-based projects.

Answer (score 0):

May be gradle needs it as DSL not Flutter

Gradle versions 5.0+ feature the Kotlin DSL, where you define your build script using the Kotlin language from JetBrains. Whilst the Groovy DSL is more common, there are some advantages in using Kotlin. Here are the top 5 reasons to switch to the Gradle Kotlin DSL.